# Migration from borland OWL to microsoft MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, migration, borland-c++

I have an application written in dependence of OWL library about every dialog is inherited from  `TDialog` class , I want to move to the recent MFC I want to depend on MFC CDialog or any of its classes instead of OWL.

Is there any guide lines to simplify the task, shorten the time and avoid the famous mistakes in such a case.

Also what is the message mapping difference between owl and mfc?

Comment: You sure you don't want to learn/utilize `c++/cli forms` programming instead?

Comment: Did you take a look at this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/owlnext/ Might help in the transition or might help avoid it completely...

Comment: thanks for you all,Mushy i like C++/CLI so much i love the mix of managed and unmanaged code technique also but i want to take advantage of MFC featurepack and mix my needed code as the all business is done in C++ also i want to secure the code-> .net can be decompiled easily , i know there are many solutions. :: Bhargav Bhat i also know about it but i need an official library that is supported

Comment: If I was in your place, I would migrate it to QT.

Comment: @sergiol : Qt is awesome but that wasn't my decision, It was a task in the job, by the way I finished it a year before.